# OG tags are not parsed into scraper

Tags: facebook, smarty

I'd like to post articles from my site onto my timeline, however somewhere along the line the metatags are emptied. For example:
http://www.uisge-beatha.eu/logboek/401/Verbouwing-koelbox-3.html
If I look at the source of the site I see the following OG-tags

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.uisge-beatha.eu/logboek/401/30/Verbouwing-koelbox-3.html" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="175931732519501" />
<meta property='og:type' content='article'> 
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.uisge-beatha.eu/logboek/401/30/Verbouwing-koelbox-3.html" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.uisge-beatha.eu/uploads/cgblog/id401&#47;Koelkast_-_30.jpg" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Verbouwing koelbox - 3" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Het testen van de compressor..." />
```

By checking the FB debugger, it sometime process it ok and sometimes it fails. All for unknown reason. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.uisge-beatha.eu%2Flogboek%2F401%2FVerbouwing-koelbox-3.html

In the case it processes ok, I do see the information I would expect based on the source of the page, by looking at the OG-metatags. However, if I look at scraper, than these metatags are empty.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.uisge-beatha.eu/Nieuwtjes.html">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="175931732519501">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:url" content="">
<meta property="og:image" content="/">
<meta property="og:title" content="">
<meta property="og:description" content="">
```

Don't know why these are empty. Been digging for an solution for hours, but find none.

The template of the site responsible for "filling" the metatages contains smarty logic:

```
<link rel="image_src" type="image/jpeg" href="{$entry->file_location}&#47;{$entry->fieldsbyname.facebook_thumbnail->value}" alt="{$entry->title|escape}" />
{if isset($canonical)}<link rel="canonical" href="{$canonical}" />
{elseif isset($content_obj)}<link rel="canonical" href="{$content_obj->GetURL()}" />
{/if}
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="175931732519501" />
<meta property='og:type' content='article'> 
<meta property="og:url" content="{$canonical}" />
<meta property="og:image" content="{$entry->file_location}&#47;{$entry->fieldsbyname.facebook_thumbnail->value}" />
<meta property="og:title" content="{$entry->title|escape}" />
<meta property="og:description" content="{$entry->summary|strip_tags:false}" />
```

Anyone who is willing to help me out on this somehow strange behaviour?